# Yii2 RestApi CORS reject when upload data

Tags: .htaccess, rest, yii2, fine-uploader

I make a RestAPI,
when post or get data it working correctly.
For example post a comment, post a status or get data.

But everytime I upload (picture) using fineuploader, It's always reject by server and return 404 error with message. but it's working fine when using postman. Here's the error message:

Firefox:

> (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

Chrome:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

This is my behavior with cors enabled in controller

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // replace to top contentNegotiator filter for displaying errors in correct format
        $content_negotiator = $behaviors['contentNegotiator'];
        unset($behaviors['contentNegotiator']);
        $content_negotiator['formats'] = Yii::$app->params['formats'];

        $behaviors = ArrayHelper::merge(
            [
                'contentNegotiator' => $content_negotiator,
                'oauth2access' => [ // should be before "authenticator" filter
                    'class' => OAuth2AccessFilter::className()
                ],
                'exceptionFilter' => [
                    'class' => ErrorToExceptionFilter::className()
                ],
                'corsFilter' => [
                    'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(), 
                    'cors' => [ 
                        'Origin' => ['*'],
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type',
                        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                        'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                    ],

                ],
            ],
            $behaviors,
            [
                'access' => [ 
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'rules' => $this->accessRules(),
                    'ruleConfig' => ['class' => 'api\components\AccessRule'],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $behaviors;
    }
```

and my .htaccess set like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Define the root domain that is allowed
    SetEnvIf Origin .+ ACCESS_CONTROL_ROOT=mydomain.com
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
    # Check that the Origin: matches the defined root domain and capture it in
    # an environment var if it does
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{ENV:ACCESS_CONTROL_ROOT} !=""
    RewriteCond %{ENV:ACCESS_CONTROL_ORIGIN} =""
    RewriteCond %{ENV:ACCESS_CONTROL_ROOT}&%{HTTP:Origin} ^([^&]+)&(https?://(?:.+?\.)?\1(?::\d{1,5})?)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=ACCESS_CONTROL_ORIGIN:%2]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    # Set the response header to the captured value if there was a match
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACCESS_CONTROL_ORIGIN}e env=ACCESS_CONTROL_ORIGIN
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and my fineuploader is like this

```
function createEventUploader() {
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        debug: false,
        multiple: false,
        element: document.getElementById('eventuploader'),
        request: {
            endpoint: apiUrl + '/uploads/event?access_token='+access_token,
            method: 'POST'
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: false,
            maxAutoAttempts: 1,
            showButton: true,
        }, 
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
            // sizeLimit: 800000,// 200 kB = 200 * 1024 bytes
        },
        cors:{
            allowXdr: true,
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: true,
        }, 
        callbacks: {
            onUpload: function(id, name) {},
            onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON) {
                var data = JSON.stringify(responseJSON);
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#eventcover').val(data.uploadName);
                }
            },
            onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                bootbox.alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem happen only on upload.
Please somebody help me with this problem.